# Store data as key value in array Java

Tags: java, arrays, key-value

In Javascript we can store values in array  like

```
var arr=[];
arr["name"]="test";
arr["value"]="result";
console.log(arr["name"]);
```

above mentioned array is storing values like key value pair,my question is this we can achieve in java without using hashmap ? so that we can get value by key in java

Comment: What's problem with hashmap? It is intended for above purpose only.

Comment: "*In java we can store values in array like...[code]*" no Java will not allow it. Did you perhaps mean JavaScript? "is this we can achieve in java without using hashmap" yes, you can write your own class which probably will behave like Map so in the end it is better to just use one of its implementations like `HashMap`.

Comment: Technically true but probably not the answer you are looking for - use [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Comment: ...and technically the Javascript example you give isn't using an array. It's using a standard Javascript object which in reality is...you guessed it... a hashmap. It uses some tricks so that it can sometimes behave like an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean you could achieve it that way, but it is much less efficient. Searching an array for a specific value will be of O(n) complexity while hashmaps only take O(1) in the best case scenario (with no chaining).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Arrays are Integer Index based in Java.

`HashMap` is specifically designed for that purpose.